# Refresh SwipeRefreshLayout from another activity

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

Activity "SubmitListActivity" contains a SwipeRefreshLayout which needs to be refreshed from within "SettingsActivity".

---

**activity_submitlist.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SubmitlistActivity">



<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainerSubmitList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/submitList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

---

**SubmitlistActivity.java**

```
 // this works!
 submitListRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipeContainerSubmitList);
 submitListRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

---

**SettingActivity.java**

```
// This throws an error
LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
View layout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_submitlist, null);
SwipeRefreshLayout submitList = layout.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainerSubmitList);
submitList.setRefreshing(true);
```

---

**Thrown Error:**

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
```

**Q1**: Is it possible to refresh the swipeRefreshLayout within the SettingsActivity?

**Q2**: When pressing back-button, the SubmitListActivity slides in again -> Is there a method I can place inside SubmitListActivity to catch this and put logic behind?

Comment: Why are you refreshing a list that's not being displayed? Just refresh it when you go back to SettingActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Refresh SwipeRefreshLayout from another activity

Calling method of one activity in another Activity isn't a good practice at all. For your problem follow below solution.

Call `submitListRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);` in your SubmitlistActivity inside your `onRestartActivity()` method like below ....

```
 @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        submitListRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    }
```

Note:- Whenever you come back from `settingActivity` to `SubmitlistActivity` onRestart() is calling.

Comment: Isn't onRestart too early? The activity isn't even in the foreground then

Comment: @ZUNJAE How it will be too early ?

Comment: That's what I am asking you

Comment: First Activity will be in background when your second activity in the foreground. When you press back button from another activity then its state change from background to foreground and onRestart() is the only method call and after that your activity other method call like onStart and onResume.

Comment: Yeah ok I get it now, I personally haven't used onRestart before. Instead I would simply attach an observer which detects changes in the settings which would then call setRefreshing. This is how I do it in my production app.

Comment: Will you post your answer over here?  So I am learn new thing. It might be useful for my further work.

Comment: Let's say you save your settings in SharedPreference, then you can attach `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to the first activity (in the `onCreate` for example). This way you don't have to rely on `onRestart` which could potentially unnecessarily call `setRefreshing` even when _no_ changes were applied to the Settings.

Comment: please share some example or your any GitHub repo where you had used it.